# JPA, Hibernate. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "")
@Table(name = "publicacao")
@NamedQuery(name = "findPubOrderByAutor", query = "SELECT publicacao FROM Publicacao pub JOIN pub.autores a WHERE a.id = :id ORDER BY pub.autores")})
public abstract class Publicacao {
    @Column(name = "autores", nullable = false)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("nome")
    @JoinTable(name = "pub_autor",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "autor_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "publicacao_id"))
    private List<Autor> autores;
}
```

And I am getting this Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode
```

-[IDENT] IdentNode: ''Publicacao'' {originalText=Publicacao}

For that NamedQuery in the class

```
"SELECT publicacao FROM Publicacao pub JOIN pub.autores a WHERE a.id = :id ORDER BY pub.autores"
```

If I replace publicacao for Publicacao I get the same error but for ...''publicacao''...

Java 7
Hibernate 3.5.5
JPA 2.0 (I think)

Please let me know if I missed some importante information.

I don't know what to do since it points me the same error both for the table and the object name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY pub.autores
```

This is probably the reason of the exception. Ordering by a collection doesn't make sense.

Another problem is

```
SELECT publicacao
```

`publicacao` is not an alias defined in the query. You should use `select pub` instead.

Also, you shouldn't have the `@Column` annotation on `autores`. It's a ManyToMany association, and is thus not mapped as a column. And you also use `inverseJoinColumns` where you should use `joinColumns`, and vice-versa.

Comment: I was about to post about finding out about the alias. Thanks for the warning about the order.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is only due to use of undefined alias. Instead of writing 
`SELECT publicacao` write `SELECT pub`.

After change code will look this,

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo", discriminatorType =    DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "")
@Table(name = "publicacao")
@NamedQuery(name = "findPubOrderByAutor", query = "SELECT pub FROM Publicacao pub JOIN pub.autores a WHERE a.id = :id ORDER BY pub.autores")})
public abstract class Publicacao {
    @Column(name = "autores", nullable = false)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("nome")
    @JoinTable(name = "pub_autor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "autor_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "publicacao_id"))
    private List<Autor> autores;
}
```